# how to use an if equals false with a number assigned string

Tags: javascript

So im trying to make my code run again if it assigns undefined as what im printing to my console, basically I have an entire array put through a math. to assign each different part of the array to a number, but sometimes it comes through as undefined so i tried fixing that with an Number.isInteger, aswell as an If false. Basically Number.isInteger is redefining my array if its not a number to false and then the If statement handles the rest, yet its not working how i thought it would.

```js
var name = new Array("bloods edge", "grass cutter", "death bringer", "yellow harbinger", "flame cutter", "ice shooter", "Big Hurt", "gun", "big gun", "bigger gun", "biggg gun", "biggest gun", "big sword", "sword", "bigger sword", "big swords brother");

var name = name[Math.floor(Math.random() * 17)];


var name = name[Number.isInteger];
console.log(name);
if (name = false) {
  var name = new Array("bloods edge", "grass cutter", "death bringer", "yellow harbinger", "flame cutter", "ice shooter", "Big Hurt", "gun", "big gun", "bigger gun", "biggg gun", "biggest gun", "big sword", "sword", "bigger sword", "big swords brother");

  var name = name[Math.floor(Math.random() * 17)];
  console.log(name);
  console.log("Attack Damage");
};
console.log(name);
console.log("Attack Damage");
const Damage = (Math.random() * 100);
console.log(Math.ceil(Damage));
var prefix = new Array("Swings with a burst of fire!", "Inflicts Posion!", "A very sharp boy", "Shoots discs of mana", "Sometimes kills instantly", "Sometimes heals you to max health");
var prefix = prefix[Math.floor(Math.random() * 6)];
if (Damage >= 70) {
  console.log("PREFIX FOR BEING GOD WOW!");
  console.log(prefix);
};
var badPrefix = new Array("broken to bits", "sometimes inflicts no damage", "inflicts self damage", "why would you use this???", "seriously stop using me", "Insults you everytime you swing", "just rude");
var badPrefix = badPrefix[Math.floor(Math.random() * 7)];
if (Damage <= 30) {
  console.log("Prefix for being BAD");
  console.log(badPrefix);
};
```

Comment: Please make correction in your if condition "if (name = false) {" You are using assignment operator to check the condition, it should be "if (name == false) {"

Comment: Why have you used the same name for a variable again and again? `name` is being repeated again and again. Isn't that giving an error?

Comment: @CodeFingers im using the same name for the same variable redifining and adding numerical value to it it Im quiet new to javascript and thats the best way I can see to use it.

Comment: Yep I understood afterwards and provided an answer

Comment: What is this line supposed to do: `var name = name[Number.isInteger];`?  In practice it tries to assign `name['function () {[ * native code * ]}']` to `name`. Also, if the script is in the global scope, `name` is a type-protected property of `window`, it can contain only string.

Comment: @Teemu Im not exactly sure what you mean as im new to JS but Number.isInterger, is supposed to redefine name to the boolean false if before hand the variable name is indefined, basically im trying to determine if name is = undefined then change it to false for the code to run again, basically changing it from undefined to a defined string.

Comment: You've to call the [method](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number/isInteger) and pass `name` as an argument, not use it as a key. Notice, that everywhere where you log `name`, it's a string, ex. `"undefined"`, not `undefined`, use another variable name than `name`.

Comment: @JoshuaSearles - Also check these lines of codes at every place, you are multiplying Math.random by the total number of elements in an array, however it should be( total number of element -1) something like this  [Math.floor(Math.random() * ARRAY_LENGTH - 1]

Comment: @Teemu I dont really understand what you mean, Thanks for your time.

Comment: @SachinVairagi Why would it need to remove one from the length, or is that not what the code is doing? Either way thanks for trying to help, im going to stop trying to fix this.

Answer (score 1):

You are using the assignment operator for the if case. You need the equality operator either use `==` or `===` there.

## This is how it should be:

```js
if (name === false) {
  var name = new Array("bloods edge", "grass cutter", "death bringer", "yellow harbinger", "flame cutter", "ice shooter", "Big Hurt", "gun", "big gun", "bigger gun", "biggg gun", "biggest gun", "big sword", "sword", "bigger sword", "big swords brother");

  var name = name[Math.floor(Math.random() * 17)];
  console.log(name);
  console.log("Attack Damage");
};
```

Maybe this is what you are looking for:

```js
var name = ["bloods edge", "grass cutter", "death bringer", "yellow harbinger", "flame cutter", "ice shooter", "Big Hurt", "gun", "big gun", "bigger gun", "biggg gun", "biggest gun", "big sword", "sword", "bigger sword", "big swords brother"];
let randomNum=Math.floor(Math.random() * 17)
var name = name[randomNum];


//var name = name[Number.isInteger];
console.log(name);
if (name === false) {
  var name = ["bloods edge", "grass cutter", "death bringer", "yellow harbinger", "flame cutter", "ice shooter", "Big Hurt", "gun", "big gun", "bigger gun", "biggg gun", "biggest gun", "big sword", "sword", "bigger sword", "big swords brother"];

  var name = name[Math.floor(Math.random() * 17)];
  console.log(name);
  console.log("Attack Damage");
};
console.log(name);
console.log("Attack Damage");
const Damage = (Math.random() * 100);
console.log(Math.ceil(Damage));
var prefix = new Array("Swings with a burst of fire!", "Inflicts Posion!", "A very sharp boy", "Shoots discs of mana", "Sometimes kills instantly", "Sometimes heals you to max health");
var prefix = prefix[Math.floor(Math.random() * 6)];
if (Damage >= 70) {
  console.log("PREFIX FOR BEING GOD WOW!");
  console.log(prefix);
};
var badPrefix = new Array("broken to bits", "sometimes inflicts no damage", "inflicts self damage", "why would you use this???", "seriously stop using me", "Insults you everytime you swing", "just rude");
var badPrefix = badPrefix[Math.floor(Math.random() * 7)];
if (Damage <= 30) {
  console.log("Prefix for being BAD");
  console.log(badPrefix);
};
```

Comment: I changed it to == aswell as ===, Its fixed the console error, however its now printing undefined.

Comment: @JoshuaSearles Okay let me see

Comment: Well I guess il give up on trying to fix that, Thanks for your help Code, however your code is basically recreating console.log, and undefined still shows up.

Comment: @JoshuaSearles i am still sorry to hear that.